# Want to use Solidworks through RDP - Any graphics card recommendations

Tags: graphics-cards, windows

Maybe this is more of a networking issue, but other than a card with Solidworks-recommended specs, is there a graphics card for a machine that will be running Solidworks that will best allow me to RDP to that machine (Windows 10)? I would like this to work sort of how Fusion360 does, using the Solidworks machine like it is 'in the cloud'.

Before anyone says "just use Fusion" - I have Solidworks and will be using that.

Comment: RDP can't use the remote GPU properly, it inserts its own 'fake' screen & drivers. If you start a high-intensity app over RDP it may fail to launch. You may have to launch it locally then RDP into it once it's running… which would be tough if you have no physical access to the machine. Perhaps look into being able to launch it on a delay from a script running locally, then RDP in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some more googling, I found that using the GPU during an RDP session can be done after the RDP 10 update with some registry changes and a GPU that is DirectX 11.0 compatible.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-10-avc-h-264-improvements-in-windows/ba-p/249588

https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/knowledge-base/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/

There are more references to this that can be done with some googling.